# how do I order the output of the head tags in joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have installed a plugin in joomla 3 that adds og: tags in the head of the page and some other components that manually place their own javascript libraries and css files.

The placement happens randomly for me since I have no way to order them.

I need to place the og tags above the javascript code.

So how do I order the output of the head tags? Is it possible?

For example:

```
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <base href="http://websiteurl.com" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="some keywords" />
  <meta name="author" content="Super User" />
  <meta name="description" content="somedescription" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />
  <title>Κεντρική</title>
  <link href="http://websiteurl.com" rel="canonical" />
  <link href="/templates/websiteurl/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <link href="http://websiteurl.com/el/component/search/?format=opensearch" rel="search" title="Αναζήτηση fmagreece.com" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://websiteurl.com/plugins/content/socialsharebuttons/style/style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://websiteurl.com/plugins/system/shadowbox/shadowbox/examples/build/shadowbox.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jui/css/bootstrap-extended.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/mod_languages/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/mod_ariextmenu/mod_ariextmenu/js/css/menu.min.css" type="text/css" />

  <meta property='og:url' content='http://fmabrotherhood.com/el/'>
  <meta property='og:type' content='article'>
  <meta property='og:title' content='main '>
  <meta property='og:description' content='some description'>
  <meta property='og:image' content='http://websiteurl.com/images/welcomeswstows.jpg'>

<link href="/templates/fmafilipinomartialartstemplate/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

And change it to

```
<head>    
  <meta property='og:url' content='http://fmabrotherhood.com/el/'>
  <meta property='og:type' content='article'>
  <meta property='og:title' content='main '>
  <meta property='og:description' content='some description'>
  <meta property='og:image' content='http://websiteurl.com/images/welcomeswstows.jpg'>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <base href="http://websiteurl.com" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="some keywords" />
  <meta name="author" content="Super User" />
  <meta name="description" content="somedescription" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />
  <title>Κεντρική</title>
  <link href="http://websiteurl.com" rel="canonical" />
  <link href="/templates/websiteurl/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <link href="http://websiteurl.com/el/component/search/?format=opensearch" rel="search" title="Αναζήτηση fmagreece.com" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://websiteurl.com/plugins/content/socialsharebuttons/style/style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://websiteurl.com/plugins/system/shadowbox/shadowbox/examples/build/shadowbox.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jui/css/bootstrap-extended.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/mod_languages/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/mod_ariextmenu/mod_ariextmenu/js/css/menu.min.css" type="text/css" />

<link href="/templates/fmafilipinomartialartstemplate/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would most likely need to edit the plug-in. Generally simple plug-ins like this just search and replace a section of the html before the page is rendered.

For example, I looked at this one....
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/open-graph/17810

This looks for the tag `</title>` and places the OG content after that.  Yours is likely to work in a similar way.

Pretty sure Facebook don't mind where in the head you place their tags, however.